# Module '"vue-final-modal"' has no exported member 'ModalsContainer'.ts(2305)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api, vue-typescript

"vue-final-modal": "^3.4.11" -> upgrade to "vue-final-modal": "^4.4.5",
"vue": "^3.3.4",
with composition API, TS, vite

OS
Windows

After build command I got an error TS2305: Module '"vue-final-modal"' has no exported member 'ModalsContainer'.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why 3 and not 4 is in use?

Comment: @EstusFlask I upgraded to to 4 if u talking about vue-final-modal but the output is the same

Comment: Consider reinstalling the packages and make sure there's the right one in node_modules. I don't see how it's possible. There's no ModalsContainer indeed in 3 https://unpkg.com/browse/vue-final-modal@3.4.11/types/index.d.ts . But it exists in 4 https://unpkg.com/browse/vue-final-modal@4.4.5/dist/index.d.ts

Comment: @EstusFlask i saw why i used 3 because i am using import { vfmPlugin } from 'vue-final-modal'; and i am injecting vfm to be able to open the dialog

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on version 3.4.11 just don't import { ModalsContainer } its rendering the component without importing.